# Inserting multiple records in for loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to store multiple records in my database but I'm getting errors. At the moment I have this:

```
$array=array('key'=>'value');
for($i = 0; $i < $something; $i++){
    array_add($array,'key','value')
}
DB::table('table')->insert($array);
```

Whenever I `var_dump($array);` It wont show the values of the `array_add` I add into the array.

What am I doing wrong and how should I insert like this?

Comment: Check if you exceed the maximum query size.

Comment: please edit your post and show your insert function too..

Comment: @Yair.R My insert is right there... It's the: `DB::table('table')->insert($array);` This is in the Laravel framework query builder.

Comment: At least your array is mismatched, it starts array('key' => 'value'); and than in for loop it is array('key', 'value'); which are different...

Comment: @taliezin `=>` and `,` do the same in this case? I've already tried to get both of them the same. Either `=>` or `,`

Comment: @Loko please put  `dd($array)` before `DB::table('table')->insert($array);` and post the result.

Comment: @mininoz I did. Take a look at the edit.

Comment: @Loko: Just for clarification, if your table columns are column1 and column2 if you create array('column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2') is the result the same?

Comment: @taliezin yes it is.

Comment: I editted the question again. Code changed

Comment: 1) Does your table have multiple columns? i.e. should one record be array('col1' => 'value1', 'col2 => 'value2' ...) etc. ") 2) Does the  'DB::table('table')->insert($array)' function accept multiple records to insert or will it only work with a single record? 3) i am not aware of a standard function 'array_add'. Unless you have created this function then your code will likely throw errors.

Comment: @RyanVincent 1. Yes it does. 2.DB::table('table')->insert does accept multiple records to insert.  3. About the array_add, it's a thing from Laravel. I tagged Laravel in the question.

Comment: @RyanVincent In Laravel you can insert multiple records like I try to do. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: It may help us if you provide a simple example of a couple of the records you wish to insert with the one 'DB::table' insert function. Please edit your question with the examples rather than posting them as a  comment.

Comment: @RyanVincent I already kinda fixed this issue. lukasgeiter his answer worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are currently doing inside the `for` loop is setting `key => value` again and again. Instead you want to add an array with `key => value` to an array containing all the rows:

```
$rows = array(
    array('key' => 'value'),
    array('key' => 'value2'),
    // and so on...
);
for($i = 0; $i < $something; $i++){
    $rows[] = array('key' => 'value');
}
DB::table('table')->insert($rows);
```

Comment: What if I had like 5 standard values. I just have to add a line of: `$array[]=array('key2'=>'value2');` for every instance?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by standard values. 5 values that are the same for every row?

Comment: no like the first line you have atm. The first line of that code, already inserts a standard value. The for loop however, inserts different values the whole time depending on the `$something`(in my normal code) What if I wanted to add more values before the for loop like you did on the first line?

Comment: Then yes, just add some more lines. You can do it like you suggested in your first comment or like my edit shows.

Comment: I still have a problem with the outcome of the query though. I'm getting: `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`. I know this means that what I'm trying to insert in a foreign key, doesn't exist, but I am 100% sure that the value that's going to insert in the foreign key, does exist. The query it shows in the error is kinda messed up as well. It says the error is at: `FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES companies` . The query it shows is: `SQL: insert into table (company_id) values (3), ('value'), etc...`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `'value'` is not a `company_id`. If you want me to help you, please edit your question with the real code you currently have and your table structure.

Comment: I will but the thing is. The query itself is messed up. The `('value')` should be inserted in a different column than company_id. I'll edit my question though

Comment: Thanks but I have to see your real code and table structure. I can only tell you that for every sub-array you add to `$rows` you insert another row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72648/discussion-between-loko-and-lukasgeiter).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to this question. Hope this help.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/update-multiple-rows-in-a-foreach-loop?page=1#reply-27859

Comment: This is not an answer to my problem.

Comment: Hey @Loko, this is a multiple UPDATE, but you can use same approach to do multiple INSERT instead.

Answer (score 0):

More a comment than an answer...  Completely untested code...

Given my interpretation of the question - I think the code should look something like this....

If you wanted to add more than one record then an extra loop enclosing the 'newRecord' would be required.

Feel free to post comments if i misunderstood the question.

```
$allRecordsToInsert = array();

$newRecord = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $something; $i++) { // add columns to 'newRecord'
    array_add($newRecord, $curColKey, $curColValue);
}
// append new record to list of records to be inserted
$allRecordsToInsert[] = $newRecord;

DB::table('table')->insert($allRecordsToInsert);
```